# Commentor get remove comment options only on their comment

Tags: php, mysql, select, comments

So I have this table and two sql statements. I want to give commentor 3 from the first query, the ability to remove their comment by using $CommentorProfOwnerOpts, which appears in the comments part being pulled out from the second query.

What happens now is that commentor 2 also gets the $CommentorProfOwnerOpts, when only commentor 3 should get them and ONLY on their comment.

```
comment_id | comment_title | commentor_id | profile_owner_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
     4          Title 1           2                1
     5          Title 2           3                1
```

```
//Commentor 3
$commentor = mysql_query("SELECT commentor_id, comment_id FROM comments WHERE commentor_id=3 AND profile_owner_id=1");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($commentor);
    if ($count > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($commentor)){    
            $commID = $row["comment_id"];
            $CommentorProfOwnerOpts = '<span id="remove-'.$commID.'">Remove Comment</span>';
    }
```

And here are the comments:

```
//All Comments for profile owner 1
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT comment_id, comment_title FROM comments WHERE profile_owner_id=1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments)){ 
            $comment_id = $row["comment_id"];
            $comment_title = $row["comment_title"];
            $CommentorProfOwnerOpts = '<span id="remove-'.$comment_ID.'">Remove Comment</span>';

            $comments .= '<div id="$comment_id" class="comments">
                          '.$comment_title.'
                          '.$CommentorProfOwnerOpts.'
                          </div>'
    }
```

The issue is that I can't figure out how to have each commentor get the remove option `$CommentorProfOwnerOpts`, appear only for their own comment, and not on another comment. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont you use some kind of login system with sessions where u can store the users id in the session?

if u dont then i advise you do orelse it will be very dificult to achieve what u want

Comment: then something like `if($_SESSION['id'] == $row['commentor_id']){ $CommentorProfOwnerOpts = '<span id="remove-'.$comment_ID.'">Remove Comment</span>'; }` should work

Comment: that still gives commentor 3 the remove option on all other comments, not just theirs:(

Comment: u dont select the commentor_id in ur mysql query `SELECT comment_id, comment_title, commentor_id FROM comments WHERE profile_owner_id=1"`